# Access view property when calling render as a callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, properties

I have to use the `guid` variable in the `render()` function, but I can pass it only to the constructor. I  this code:

```
app.views.CompanyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#company-view',
    guid: '',

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.guid = options.guid;
    },

    render: function () {
        var guid = this.guid;
    }
});
```

I create my view like this:

```
app.currentView = new app.views.CompanyView({guid: guid});
```

Then I pass the `render()` function as a parameter to use it as a callback:

```
function call(callback){
    callback();
}

call(app.currentView.render);
```

I tried `this.guid`, `options` and `this.options` too, but all of them were `undefined`. Is there a way to pass this variable to the `render()` function without using it's arguments or global variables? Here is a [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/p25tY/).

Comment: Seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/cn8nN/

Comment: You should be able to access this.guid in render() unless render() is called by other objects. in that case, you will need to add _.bindAll(this, "render"); in your initialize.

Comment: @nikoshr I found out that the problem occurs only when I use the render function as a callback. Updated your fiddle, so now it reproduces my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `render` through this:

```
function call(callback){
    callback();
}
```

You're calling it as a plain function so `this` inside `render` will be `window`. Remember that `this` in JavaScript depends on how the function is called, not how it is defined (unless of course you're playing with bound functions).

You have some options:

1. Bind `render` to the view using [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll), [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), ...

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       _.bindAll(this, 'render');
   }
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GsUfY/
2. The more common approach these days is to pass a context with the function and then whoever calls the callback uses the appropriate context using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

   ```
   function call(callback, context){
       callback.apply(context);
   }
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LnwPr/
3. Do it yourself by hand:

   ```
   call(function() { v.render() });
   ```

   This one usually takes the form of `var _this = this;` followed by an anonymous function that uses `_this.some_method()` instead of just passing `this.some_method` as a callback.

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/K2Xj4/

I prefer the second option.

Answer (score 2):

I see. When your render() is called by the callback function, the caller of the method is no longer the view itself, so the "this" inside your render will be the caller of the call function().

see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cn8nN/2/

```
var CompanyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
      this.guid = options.guid;
  },

  render: function () {
    console.log('hello');
    console.log(this);
  }
});

var v = new CompanyView({guid: 'the guid'});

function call(callbcak) {
  callbcak();
}

call(v.render);
```

if you open the console, you  will see "this " is actually the window.

to work around this, you want to bind the context to the view it self.

to do that, use _.bindAll();

```
initialize: function (options) {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.guid = options.guid;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cn8nN/3/